# Java ImageIO read image byte[] into pre-allocated BufferedImage

Tags: java, arrays, image, memory, bufferedimage

I'm working with ImageIO and JAI and want to read a byte array into a `BufferedImage`. The `byte[]` contains data for a JP2000 encoded image, and it's fairly large, around 100MB. I'm currently doing something like:

```
byte[] imageDataBytes = ...
InputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageDataBytes);
BufferedImage imageData = ImageIO.read(imageStream);
```

It seems that ImageIO is creating a `new BufferedImage` each time `read()` is called.

**Question:**

Is there a way to tell ImageIO to read and decode the image byte data into a pre-allocated mutable `BufferedImage`?

I did some searching through the Javadocs and found that the `BufferedImage` stores its data in a `Raster` object, which stores its data in a `DataBuffer` object. So I'm aware any solution that exists will technically not be writing to the `BufferedImage`, but instead will be directly writing to the `DataBuffer`.

It may help to know that all images are the same size: roughly 10,000 x 10,000, so there shouldn't be any problems with the read image not aligning with the buffered image. Ultimately, I would like to have an object pool of buffered images, or rasters, or data buffers, and borrow from the pool every time I read using ImageIO. Something like this pseudocode:

```
InputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageDataBytes);
WritableRaster raster = ObjectPool.getAvailableRaster();
ImageIO.readToRaster(imageStream, raster);
BufferedImage imageData = new BufferedImage(raster);
```

I'm sure there's a simple solution out there. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) delegates its work to ImageReader (and Writers). All that is detail rich. I would first look for an alternative to byte arrays and byte array input streams as such. And look for a JPEG2000 ImageReader.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however looking at the implementation of the `read()` method, it already converts the byte stream into an image reader. At its core, it calls an abstract read() method defined as: `public abstract BufferedImage read(int imageIndex, ImageReadParam param)`. Is there any way to pass an already instantiated `BufferedImage` or `WritableRaster` object as an argument to the `read()` method?

Comment: Just to clarify, the "core" read method belongs to the ImageReader object, but it has no implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can [set the destination image](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/ImageReadParam.html#setDestination(java.awt.image.BufferedImage)) of an ImageReadParam object.  However, there is a caveat:  the BufferedImage must have a ColorModel and SampleModel that match the image being loaded.

I’m not sure about JPEG2000 images, but regular JPEGs are usually RGB images, so an image of [TYPE_INT_RGB](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_INT_RGB) should suffice:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(10000, 10000,
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

while (bytesAvailable) {
    byte[] imageDataBytes = getImageBytes();

    try (InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageDataBytes);
         ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(in)) {

        ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream).next();
        reader.setInput(stream);

        ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();
        param.setDestination(image);

        reader.read(0, param);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Just curious, would it be sensible to put the try block outside of the while loop so I don't create so many input streams or am I missing something?

Comment: @billschmidt626 You will need a new ImageInputStream for each array of bytes.

Comment: Are you saying I would need multiple input streams for just one image? For the `getImageBytes()` method you refer to, does that return the entire image, or different images, or different tiles of the image, or just chunks of the image bytes?

Comment: I assume getImageBytes is a method that returns the bytes of a JPEG, encoded as a JPEG.  I also assume that each of your images is a different byte array.

Comment: Ah okay. Now I understand, you've written it to handle multiple images. Two steps ahead of me! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

For those who find themselves in this situation, the answer by VGR works well. I like to add that specifically for JPEG-2000 images that contain metadata, use

```
reader.setInput(stream, true, true);
```

instead of

```
reader.setInput(stream);
```

This avoids a NullPointer exception. you can read more about it here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2103